# Get facebook userID with sender.id

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

So here is the change event webhook sends me when my page receives a msg :

```
 {
 "object":"page",
 "entry":
    [{"id":"718511138248476","time":1470310180982,
        "messaging":
            [{"sender":{"id":"845775748857562"},
            "recipient":{"id":"718511138248476"},
            "timestamp":1470310180901,
            "message":
                {"mid":"mid.1470310180891:612cfb6aead5fca278",
                "seq":468,
                "text":"hello"}
            }]
    }]}
```

But then how should I know which user is actually sending this message ? Is there some way to get the user facebook ID with sender.id ?

And for the second question : is sender.id always the same or it will be changed ? I mean is it wise to save the sender.id in database for when I'm intending to send a msg to the user later on ?

Comment: Messenger user ids are page-scoped. If you want to get details about the user: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile

Comment: I know, but to use that I need the UserID. While this response from webhook only gives me the sender ID which is a different ID.

Comment: The sender id _is_ the user id you need to query that API.

Comment: There are three types of ID you should consider: global facebook ID (not available for you), app-scoped ID (available through facebook login) and page-scoped ID (available through messenger platform). Now you cannot tell if it's the same user hiding behind app-scoped or page-scoped but there are some hacks available out there https://chatbotsmagazine.com/fb-messenger-bot-how-to-identify-a-user-via-page-app-scoped-user-ids-f95b807b7e46#.dyef9veza

Comment: Is there anyone knows how to get messenger_id, given I have fb_user_id got from FB.login....function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read document here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile . But response fields do not have "id".

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has the ID matching API, you should give it a try
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/id-matching

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.